# Weblogic Server contains NONE value during session ID generation

Tags: weblogic12c

We have setup weblogic 12.2.1.4 clustered environment with 2 nodes in a cluster. We use session ID as part of authentication mechanism to log our user session info to the database. When both managed servers are up, the server generates this session ID:

***MrvgJEMe6NG95XNsflnhsWjspl52GXPdl33whbIfGkgaEQm7Rk0X!1974917613!-533469515!1605782630842***

When we tried to test session replication, by bringing down the server that currently serves the HTTP request, we have noticed that the session ID has changed and contains **NONE** as part of the generated ID.

***MrvgJEMe6NG95XNsflnhsWjspl52GXPdl33whbIfGkgaEQm7Rk0X!1974917613!NONE!1605782630842***

This has caused session replication inconsistency. Has anyone encountered the same issue and how did you resolve it? Your inputs are highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Debug Flags to Track Session Replication Failures
To gather more logging information about session replication failures, you should enable the flags DebugCluster, DebugClusterAnnouncements, DebugFailOver, DebugReplication, and DebugReplicationDetails.

To Enable:
In WebLogic Server 9.x and higher, the reccommended approach is to use the admin console. For each server in the domain, navigate to Servers ->  -> Debug and enable the desired flag(s).
You can use the weblogic.Admin command line utility to dynamically turn the debug options on and off.

For example, to turn on DebugCluster on all administration instances of ServerDebug Mbean (i.e., Admin Server or a Managed Server):
java weblogic.Admin -url t3://localhost:7001 -username system -password weblogic SET -type ServerDebug -property DebugCluster true
Alternatively, you can edit the config.xml and the Mbean element in the  stanza for each server that you want to debug and set the value to "true" to enable or "false" to disable. Then you must restart the Admin Server. Managed Servers will reconnect to the Admin Server and the debug flags will then dynamically take effect. Example:

At the end, with all the flags set, in your config.xml the ServerDebug tag would like below:

Make sure the stdOutSeverity level of the server is INFO and StdoutDebugEnabled is set to "true". The debug information will be logged into the server log as well as to the standard out.
Validate the Weblogic.xml entries
Make sure weblogic.xml has all the parameters that need to be set for each Session Replication type. For example, when using in-memory replication the sample weblogic.xml would look like:
[image]

Comment: jaymarco, thank you for sharing. I have tried the configuration in weblogic admin console with DebugFailOver and DebugLoadBalancing. The rest cannot be enabled as I could not find it. In addition, got this validation problem in weblogic.xml when I added session-param: **cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected elements 'timeout-secs, invalidation-interval-secs, max-save-post-size, save-post-timeout-secs, ..., monitoring-attribute-name, sharing-enabled, invalidate-on-relogin,' instead of 'session-param@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app' here in element session-descriptor. **